# Отслеживание gsm трафика

Tags: железо, связь

Здравствуйте, возможно ли как-нибудь подсчитать сколько мобильных устройств находится в определенной области, и какое для этого нужно оборудование ? 
Заранее спасибо :)

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что такие вопросы не входят в тематику RU.SO. Вам на radioscanner.ru